# Running protractor e2e on Firefox

Tags: firefox, selenium, protractor, angularjs-e2e, e2e-testing

I have a site which uses client certificate to authenticate the user and I want to do e2e testing for that site

I tried to run protractor with firefox browser, it opens the browser but then it is not asking for user identification(screen to ask user to pick the client certificates).

I have tried using chrome and it asks for the SSL certificate to choose but for firefox no luck, can somebody guide me on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selenium webdriver and, by extension, Protractor does not usually support the latest versions of Firefox. To ensure you are using a supported version, do not use "directconnect" in your protractor config file. You should use the firefox driver with a selenium server spun up.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I tried directconnect=false and I can see the firefox browser is opener but it says "SSL peer cannot verify your certificate. (Error code: ssl_error_bad_cert_alert) " Do you think the firefox is picking up a cert by default?